# Haskell Peano Numbers and Laziness in Multiplication

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, multiplication, peano-numbers

I started learning Haskell recently and in my class right now, we have constructed a Peano number class and instanced it in the Num typeclass.

During lecture, my professor claimed that depending on whether you viewed the successor function as `S x = x + 1` or `S x = 1 + x`, the appropriate successor case for the multiplication definition would be different. Respectively:

```
x * S y = x * y + x
x * S y = x + x * y
```

Moreover, he claimed that using the first of these two choices is preferable because it is lazier but I'm having trouble seeing how this is the case.

We looked at the example in which the addition definition of

```
x + S y = S (x + y)
```

is better than

```
x + S y = S x + y
```

because evaluating `x + y == z` occurs much faster but I can't find an analogous case for multiplication.

The lecture notes are here: http://cmsc-16100.cs.uchicago.edu/2014/Lectures/lecture-02.php

Comment: there seem to be lots of small errors in your question

Comment: I really don't know what to make of your first question as the definition of the multiplication does not use the successor function (only the `S` type constructor and you cannot define this any different)

Comment: for the rest I have to say I cannot put it better than your prof in the link you gave - the explanation is quite good IMHO - maybe you can copy out the parts you don't understand and we can talk about them

Comment: and just saw - the other question is homework/excercise too - HINT: do the same as with the different kinds of multiplikation (expand the definitions on paper and see what's shorter) - BTW that course seems really good - wish I had similar in my time :)

Comment: concerning the first question: I think you should forget the "1+x" vs "x+1" part and just try to figure out if `x * y + x` or `x + x * y` (aka "x*(y+1)" vs "x*(1+y)" is better in with the defintion you have -

Comment: Thanks Carsten, I'll go through the notes another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laziness is not about *speed* but what is available *how soon*.

With `x * S y = x * y + x` then you can answer `infinity * 2 > 5` very quickly, because it will expand as so:

```
infinity * (S (S Z)) > 5
infinity * (S Z) + infinity > 5
infinity * Z + infinity + infinity > 5
infinity + infinity > 5
```

(from there the rest is trivial)

However, I don't think it is all as good as your professor claimed! Try to expand out `2 * infinity > 5` in this formalism and you'll be disappointed (or busy for a very long time :-P). On the other hand, with the other definition of multiplication, you *do* get an answer there.

Now, if we have the "good" definition of addition, I *think* it should be the case that you can get an answer with infinities in *either* position. And indeed, I checked the source of a few Haskell packages that define Nats, and indeed they prefer `x * S y = x + x * y` rather than the way your professor claimed was better.